# Ошибка открытия файла из-за русских букв в пути

Tags: java

Пишу свой JUnit, хочу что бы в stack trace были ссылки, щелкнув на которые открывался бы нужный файл.
Вот так у меня отображается stack trace:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылки кликабельные, все хорошо. Но когда кликаю по ним, получаю исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Там где краказябры, это у меня в пути папка по-русски называется. Пробовал открыть файл без русских букв в пути - все открывается. Как то можно открывать файл с русскими буквами в пути?

Comment: Попробуйте `URLDecoder.decode(string, "utf-8")`. По ощущениям, проще в `<href=''>...</a>` поместить какие-то свои данные, а ссылку на файл получать уже в обработчике нажатия через `Paths.get(путь_к_файлу_с_русскими_буквами_пробелами_и_прочим).toUri()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать следующее:

Допустим, ты получаешь полный путь к файлу так:

```
String path = new File("file.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

А ты попробуй перевести из традиционной русской кодировки `Windows-1251` в `UTF-8` следующим образом:

```
String path = new String(new File("file.txt").getAbsolutePath().getBytes("WINDOWS-1251"));
```

Comment: не сработало( та же ошибка осталась

Comment: тогда попробуй вместо "WINDOWS-1251" написать "UTF-8".

Comment: Не мудрите `String path = new File("file.txt").getAbsolutePath();` вполне достаточно. Смотрите кодировку в вашей "консоли", т.е. в окне, куда вы выводите stackTrace.

Comment: Ну так у него же не работает, что ещё мудрить то?

Answer (score 0):

Не совпадают кодировки там, где ты читаешь имя имя файла и там, где ты его выводишь на экран. Надо привести к общему знаменателю.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так

```
private static String decodeGetParameter(String parameter) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String(URLDecoder.decode(parameter, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
    }
```